# How to specify channel icon/photo for Apple News app

Tags: apple-news

Apple seems to have no documentation for how they pull the main image for your channel in Apple News.

This one here:

[image]

I have og:image tags on my site + the apple-touch-icon meta. I also have images in my RSS feed. It's showing up blank.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're now FINALLY able to choose the image yourself by going to the Apple News Publisher and then going to **Channel Info > Cover**

Answer (score 3):

Just to give you an answer, they told me that:

"You are not able to submit a custom cover image for your channel at this time. However, if thumbnails for images within your articles are properly referenced by the og:image tag, with dimensions of at least 600 x 400 pixels, the thumbnail from your most recent article will take the place of the colored tile."